# Android jar and source code mismatch?

Tags: android, jar

I have been looking through the android source code for ICS and JB (API15 &  API16) and am finding what appears (to me) to be a mismatch between the code and the jar files. More specifically, in SpeechRecognizer.java there is a reference to Settings.Secure.VOICE_RECOGNITION_SERVICE, which is defined in android/provider/Settings.java under the subclass Secure as

```
public static final String VOICE_RECOGNITION_SERVICE = "voice_recognition_service";
```

But when I try to reference VOICE_RECOGNITION_SERVICE from my own code, it cannot be resolved. In Eclipse, when I look through the jar file, I do not see VOICE_RECOGNITION_SERVICE defined. In fact, many of the fields in Settings.Secure which are defined as public in the java source code are not found in the jar file. I am wondering why, if the jar file was created using the source files, I cannot access VOICE_RECOGNITION_SERVICE. If a field is declared public in the source then shouldn't it be accessible from the .jar file?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same. It seems that often, some of the methods/fields are not visible for application-specific code.
However, sometimes it is possible to invoke these methods/fields by using Java reflections.